# Functions with continuous representatives on subdomains (Real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a bounded set and $f \in L^2(A)$. We suppose exists $K > 0$ and $0 < \epsilon <1$ such that for each ball $B(x,r) \subset A$ we have that:
$\int_{B(x,r)} |f(z) - f_{x,r}|\,dz \le K^2r^{n+2\epsilon} \\$ 
with $f_{x,r} = \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} f(z)\,dz $ .
Now, I have to show that if $A' \subset A$ then there exists a bounded and continuous function $\hat{f}$ on A' such that $\forall z\in A' f(z)=\hat{f}(z).\quad$
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You must be leaving something out, probably hypotheses on $A$ and $A'$. As stated the assertion has a patently absurd consequence:

> > If $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ is bounded and has empty interior and $f:A\to[0,1]$ then $f$ is continuous.

Proof: The hypothesis is satisfied, since $A$  contains no ball.  Let $A'=A$ in the conclusion.